# 3D scatter plot with highcharter in R

Tags: r, plot, r-highcharter

I have a data set and I want to plot a 3D scatter plot using highcharter package.
here is a sample code using R data sets:

```
library(highcharter)
data("USJudgeRatings")

highchart() %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Scatter chart with size") %>% 
  hc_add_series_scatter(USJudgeRatings$CONT,
           USJudgeRatings$INTG,USJudgeRatings$DECI)%>%
  hc_chart(type = "scatter", options3d = list(enabled = TRUE, alpha = 70, beta = 0))
```

but it turns in to a bubble 2D scatter plot.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, the 3D scatter plots of Highcharts are not available in `highcharter`. 
 Only 3D bar charts can be plotted (see [here](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html)). 
My suggestion is to use `plotly` for high quality interactive 3D scatter plots.
See the example below:

```
library(datasets)
data("USJudgeRatings")

library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(USJudgeRatings, x=~CONT, y=~INTG, z=~DECI, color=~PHYS) %>%
     add_markers()
print(p)
```

[image]

Another interesting R package for 3D scatter plots is [`rthreejs`](https://github.com/bwlewis/rthreejs).