# How to plot simple 3D plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

Let's take very simple data:

```
x1 <- sample(1:100, 10)
x2 <- runif(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
```

I want to make a 3D plot (x1, x2, y) but I cannot find any function how it can be performed in R. I found function `perp` but `perp(x1, x2, y)` simply returns error, that `x` and `y` is not increasing. Could you please give me a hand doing so?

Comment: in library(plot3D)  you can use e.g. scatter3D(x=sample(1:100, 10), y=runif(10), z=rnorm(10))

Comment: A quick google search leads to [this](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization), and here on SO you have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530036/3d-scatter-plot-with-highcharter-in-r) just for examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use cloud function from lattice package

```
install.packages("lattice")
library("lattice")

cloud(x1~ x2+ y)
```

you can add some options also

```
cloud(x1~ x2+ y , 
      xlab= "x1"  ,
      ylab = "x2" ,
      zlab = "y" , 
      main="3D plot of X1 x2 and Y " , 
      pch=16 , 
      aspect = c(1,1) ,
      panel.aspect = 1 ,
      screen = list(z=105 , x=70))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look at `plotly`:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly( x = x1, y = x2, z = y)
```

[image]